# How can I add a table view controller to an existing storyboard view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I'm creating a landscape iPad app for iOS 5.1 that should have *two* table views embedded into a view controller of my storyboard. What I would *like* to be able to do, is drag a table view controller onto the view controller in my storyboard. But of course, Xcode does not allow this. I can drag a table view and get its data hooked up and it works properly, but then I cannot push a new view controller to replace that table when a row is selected.

I cannot use the 'Editor > embed in > navigation controller' trick, because then the entire storyboard view controller (which contains my two table views) is embedded. That is not what I want.

There must be a way to do this programmatically, but I can't seem to get the right combo of voodoo and science to make it work.

I have tried to create a custom container view to hold my `tableViewController`, but the table isn't showing up.

Any thoughts?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(68, 187, 402, 474);
    _containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    _containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.view addSubview:_containerView];

    categoryController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    categoryTable = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    categoryTable.delegate = self;
    categoryTable.dataSource = self;

    [categoryController.view addSubview:categoryTable];
    [_containerView addSubview:categoryController.view];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is `Container Views`

Here are some tutorials that can help you:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/

http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/12383262201/container-view-controllers-part-i-one-of-the

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102

Comment: Ahh. Forgot to mention this is iOS 5.1. So container views are not supported.

Comment: You can still use them it's just not as easy as containers with seques. https://github.com/Cocoanetics/Examples/tree/master/ContainerDemo

Comment: Forgive me Space Dust, I didn't realize that. Okay, so i have been looking through your links and project (thanks), but something still isn't right. Please see my edited question.

Comment: A further study of the `UITableViewController` documentation helped me understand that when instantiated, the class automatically creates a class of `UITableView` that it contains. Therefore to set the delegate and datasource, you have to access the internal table view:
`myTableViewController.tableView.delegate = self`